# How to create a new array from two and initialize the new one based on values in original arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I'm new to Java, and I'm not sure how to ask the right question, so please bear with me. I have 40 total items of 6 different types to put into a new array; each item type has a different cost. The first item (quantity=1) costs $3, the second item (qty=2) costs $5 each, the third item (qty=4) costs $9 each, and so on. The quantity of each item type is in `numTypeIndArray` and the cost for each type is in `costCSDriverArray`. A cumulative count of the total items is in `numTypeCumulArray`.

So, the new array, `indItemCostArray`, should be single dimensional and have 40 elements. It would look something like `{3,5,5,9,9,9,9,...,13,13,13}`, but the last fifteen elements are a cost of $13. How do I get to this array with 40 elements? I started with trying to fill the array using a nested for loop but I haven't gotten there yet. The code below is plain wrong.

```
int[] costArray = new int[]{3,5,9,10,11,13};
int[] numTypeIndArray = new int[]{1,2,4,7,11,15};
int[] numTypeCumulArray = new int[]{1,3,7,14,25,40};

int[] indItemCostArray = new int[numTypeCumulArray[6]];

for (int i = 0; i < indItemCostArray.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < numTypeIndArray[i]; j++) {
        indItemCostArray[i+j] = costArray[j];
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to be a variant of the 'parellel-arrays' anti-pattern. Don't do that, create objects to hold related data together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    int[] costArray = new int[]{3,5,9,10,11,13};
    int[] numTypeIndArray = new int[]{1,2,4,7,11,15};
    int[] numTypeCumulArray = new int[]{1,3,7,14,25,40};

    int[] indItemCostArray = new int[numTypeCumulArray[5]];

    int num = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < numTypeIndArray.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < numTypeIndArray[i]; j++) {
            indItemCostArray[num + j] = costArray[i];
        }
        num += numTypeIndArray[i];
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(indItemCostArray));
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you'll get a `ArrayOutOfBoundException` at:

```
int[] indItemCostArray = new int[numTypeCumulArray[6]];
```

The size of the array `numTypeCumulArray` is 6, and arrays are 0 indexed. So, The last index number is 5, not 6, as indexing started from 0.

You can do as follows for accessing the last element of the array:

```
int[] indItemCostArray = new int[numTypeCumulArray[numTypeCumulArray.length - 1]];
```

Secondly, you're running your outer loop for `40` times and for each iteration your inner loop is trying to iterate for `numTypeIndArray[i]` times, where `i` is the iterator variable of outer loop. So, surely after sixth iteration, when value of `i` will be `6`, your program will again throw the `ArrayOutOfBoundException` as you're accessing a value in the terminator condition of the inner loop from `numTypeIndArray` whose last index is 5.

Again, inside the inner loop, you're assigning `indItemCostArray` at index position `i+j`, which will actually far from your purpose.

To achieve what you are exactly expecting, you can do as follows:

```
int currentIndex =0;

for (int costIndex = 0; costIndex < costArray.length; costIndex++) {
    for(int index = currentIndex;  index < currentIndex + numTypeIndArray[costIndex]; index++) {
        indItemCostArray[index] = costArray[costIndex];
    }
    currentIndex = numTypeCumulArray[costIndex];
}
```

Here, what I did is, in the outer loop I iterated the same amount of time the length of `costArray`, you can take the length of `numTypeIndArray` instead too, no issue. I've defined a variable named `currentIndex` to keep track of the current assignable index for array `indItemCostArray`. In the inner loop, I tried to begin with the `currentIndex` and loop upto the time same as the number of items needed for that type, given in `numTypeIndArray[costIndex]`, and for each iteration, set the corresponding index of `indItemCostArray` with the cost of `costIndex` in  the `costArray`. Finally, I update the currentIndex with the corresponding cumulative total items from `numTypeCumulArray`.

Hope you got everything clear.

Answer (score 1):

The whole setup of three arrays is kind of weird. The weiredest is the third array. Think carefully, do you actually need it? You already have all the information in your second array. The third array can introduce a lot of unnacessary mistakes.

But, assuming that you actually need these arrays for some reason and there are no mistakes in making these arrays. You can get your required fourth array as follows,

```java
int[] costArray = new int[]{3,5,9,10,11,13};
int[] numTypeIndArray = new int[]{1,2,4,7,11,15};
int[] numTypeCumulArray = new int[]{1,3,7,14,25,40};

// you want to make sure that your arrays are of same lenght
assert(costArray.length == numTypeIndArray.length && costArray.length == numTypeCumulArray.length);

// length of these arrays is unique items count
int uniqueItemsCount = costArray.length;

// totalItemsCount is last element of numTypeCumulArray
int totalItemsCount = numTypeCumulArray[uniqueItemsCount - 1];

int[] indItemCostArray = new int[totalItemsCount];

// use this to keep track of index in indItemCostArray
int itemCostIndex = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < uniqueItemsCount && itemCostIndex < totalItemsCount; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < numTypeIndArray[i] && itemCostIndex < totalItemsCount; j++) {
        indItemCostArray[itemCostIndex] = costArray[j];
        // increase the index for next item cost
        itemCostIndex += 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't need `int[] numTypeCumulArray = new int[]{1,3,7,14,25,40};`

It just shows the cumulative values of the `numTypeIndArray`.  The last value, `40` is just the sum of `numTypeIndArray` and that would be the size of the resulting array from your requirement.

It can be summed in a simple for loop or you can do it like this and then create the target array.

```
int maxSize = Arrays.stream(numTypeIndArray).sum();
int[] indItemCostArray = new int[maxSize];
```

Then you could proceed to populate the array with the values as has been shown.  Here is another way using streams which you will undoubtedly learn about.  The quick explanation is that it creates multiple streams of the proper quantities of cost.

```
e.g
stream1 -> {3}
stream2 -> {5,5};
stream3 -> {9,9,9,9} etc.
```

Then it flattens them in a single stream of those values and returns an array.

```
int[] result = IntStream.range(0, costArray.length)
        .flatMap(i -> IntStream.range(0, numTypeIndArray[i])
                .map(q -> costArray[i]))
        .toArray();
```

But using a class to hold the information would be better.  Here is one example.

```
class Product {
    private String name;
    private int cost;
    private int quantity;
    public Product(String name, int cost, int quantity) {
        this.name = name;
        this.cost = cost;
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }
    public int getCost() {
        return cost;
    }
    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    
    @Override 
    public String toString() {
        return new StringJoiner(", ","[", "]").add(name).add("cost="+cost).add("quantity="+quantity).toString();
    }
}
```

And it can be used like so.

```
List<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < costArray.length; i++) {
        products.add(new Product("Item" + (i+1), costArray[i], numTypeIndArray[i]));
}
products.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Prints

```
[Item1, cost=3, quantity=1]
[Item2, cost=5, quantity=2]
[Item3, cost=9, quantity=4]
[Item4, cost=10, quantity=7]
[Item5, cost=11, quantity=11]
[Item6, cost=13, quantity=15]
```

And once again it can be streamed to create your results exactly as before only using the class `getters` to get the values.

```
        
int[] result2 = products.stream()
        .flatMapToInt(
                prod -> IntStream.range(0, prod.getQuantity())
                        .map(q -> prod.getCost()))
        .toArray();
```

The two arrays `result` and `result2` are identical.  But you may find that using classes may eliminate the requirement for creating such an array.